# Access Xephyr session twice

Tags: gnome, 14.04, vnc, xserver

Ok ; so I've got a gnome-session running on Xephyr flawlessly . What I need is to access that session from another Xephyr window , meaning I get two windows showing the exact same display (as if I was connected via vnc) . After three days of goggling , I still have no clue . Any alternative method to get the same result (two instances of the same nested session running on a same screen) is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can do something like X forwarding via ssh.. Didn't use Xephyr before, but maybe this link can help → http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/xephyr.html